# What do I need to know before buying a domain from an individual seller?

Tags: domain-name, transaction

What steps do I need to take in order to ensure a successful transaction and protect myself from getting scammed?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to go about it is to use a 3rd-party domain escrow service.  Google (or Bing) "domain escrow" and you'll get tons of 'em.  Escrow.com comes to mind.